# Adding delete button for each image thumbnail preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to put next to each thumbnail a little cross to be able to remove them one by one. I am able to remove image by click on it but I would like to have seperate button "x" to remove it.

```
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (e) {

        var filesVAR = this.files;

        showThumbnail(filesVAR);

    }, false);



    function showThumbnail(files) {
        var file = files[0]

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
        image.file = file;

        image.setAttribute('class', 'imgKLIK5');
        thumbnail.appendChild(image)

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
            return function (e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        }(image))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my code in [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j0ont4p0/)

Can You help me out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example with close button:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/r0taz01L/1/

```
 $('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function () {
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#upload-file').val("");
    });
```

And I made this changes in your showThumbnail function

```
 function showThumbnail(files) {
        var file = files[0]
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
        var pDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        var div = document.createElement("div");


        pDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pDiv');
        thumbnail.appendChild(pDiv);


        image.setAttribute('class', 'imgKLIK5');
        pDiv.appendChild(image)

        div.innerHTML = "X";
        div.setAttribute('class', 'closeDiv');
        pDiv.appendChild(div).......
        ...................
```

Comment: Can You help me with one more thing? I got a field to sum up all the input file sizes '<input type="text" style="display:none" id="countFileSizesField" value="0" />' But when I delete one I would like to substract deleted file size from this field. How where can I find size of deleting img in this function 

' $('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function () {
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#upload-file').val("");
    });

'

Comment: @DaArtagnan can you give me code of how you will calculate image size or can you update fiddle and give me in  comment i will do that part in your fiddle

Comment: @DaArtagnan http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/r0taz01L/4/ see this example it is not possible to get image size from <img src=""> so set data attribute

Comment: @DaArtagnan it is working or not let me know if you want any help ?

Comment: Thank You very much but I abandoned method. Thank You for Your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the `img` from div `thumbnail` on click the "x" button, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/34g8jwe1/2/)

Comment: I would like to put "x" button to every single thumbnail preview. And remove not all of them but just chosen one. How Can I do that?

Comment: I updated the fiddle so the "x" button appear in the top right corner of thumbnail div

Answer (score 0):

Just add new button element on each preview with following style attributes,

```
float:right;
position:relative;
```

Comment: Can you give ma an example?

Comment: @DaArtagnan see my answer i added X button